# Terraria: Is the Inlet and Outlet Pumps only triggered when the Switch/Lever is between both?

Tags: terraria

I've been searching many guides about wiring, with my true intentions being figuring where the switch/lever has to be at allowing the inlet/outlet device to function (as one of my creations didn't seem to function). However, no guides have fully explained to me **where exactly the switches need to be positioned at for the inlet/outlet device to function appropriately**. Furthermore, additional information/links about the inlet/outlet device in particular would be deeply appreciated.

My issue could've been within the following:

1. I had already created another circuit which functioned well and transferred the water from 1 designated place unto another. Within this Circuit, I used red wiring and placed the switch far right, away from the inlet/outlet device.
2. However, I created my second circuit with blue wiring, clearly not touching nor trespassing the red wire at any parts. The switch is located far left and also away from both inlet/outlet device.

I understand it is hard to picture so I roughly drawn what I've done below.[image]

Here's an in-game screenshot as well

[image: This is the snipped Screenshot]

Comment: I don't see why your setup shouldn't work. Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: I edited the picture on Private Pansy
Red works, blue doesn't. 
Btw, I'm considerably new to wiring

Answer (score 2):

The switch can be anywhere on the wire. When a switch is activated, all devices connected to the same wire receive the signal.

As for your pumping problem: according to the wiki article on [Pumps](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pump), and confirmed by my own testing,

> When an Outlet Pump is submerged, the pumping stops.

You need to put your Outlet Pump above the water line. This pump setup will work:

[image: Working pump]

But this one will not:

[image: Not working pump]